# scala find all combinations of a list of lists

Tags: scala

How to replace an item with a list and flatten the result?

example:

replace 3 with List(a, b)

input: `List(1, 2, 3, 4)`

output:

```
List(List(1, 2, a, 4)
    List(1, 2, b, 4))
```

input: `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 3)`

output:

```
List(List(1, 2, a, 4, a)
    List(1, 2, a, 4, b)
    List(1, 2, b, 4, a)
    List(1, 2, b, 4, b))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Any problems we can help you with? BTW, in your examples, the result is not flattened, while in the begging of your question you are saying that you want it flat.

Comment: Replacing 3 with List(a,b) would result in List(1,2,(a,b),4) and flattening that would result in List(1,2,a,b,4). What you wrote is something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
def replacePermutations[A](l: Seq[A], replace: A, by: Seq[A]) = {
  val byPermutationsWithRepetitions =
    (by map (e => by.indices map (_ => e))) ++ by.permutations

  byPermutationsWithRepetitions map { by =>
    val i = Iterator.from(0)
    l map { e =>
      if (e == replace) by(i.next() % by.size)
      else e
    }
  }
}
```

Cheers